# Got error 'Trying to get property 'id' of non-object' even dd function return it right

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have to display data from `post table` based on `user`. But, I always get error

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

even though `dd($user)` and `dd($post)` return it right. `dd($user)` return 1st row, `dd($post)`return 1st row. When commenting all the 'dd' function , I got 'Trying to get property 'id' of non-object' at `$post = post::find($user->id);`. However when I `dd($post->article_title, $post->id)`,[I do get the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21gUH.png)

```
    $RMM = DB::table('companies')->where('branch', 'RMM')->get();
    foreach ($RMM as $RMM) {
        $user = User::find($RMM->id);
        $post = post::find($user->id);
        $post_data = array('title' => $post->article_title,
            'name' => $post->author,
            'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post->date)),
        );
```

[result of `dd(post)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRUvH.png)

[result of `dd(user)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKOqP.png)

Comment: Could you post the output from your dd()'s ?

Comment: dude you are using `$RMM as $RMM` same variable name in local scope change your variable name to small letter or anyother `foreach ($RMM as $rmm) {}` and now try

Comment: @SalmanZafar, in my understanding, the capital and small latter does not make such difference in foreach loop since the next var just overwrite the previous var, in this case, 2nd `$RMM` overwrite the 1st `$RMM` . But, I did try and it just same with original.

Comment: @Ruub I editted the question and add 2 pictures of result for dd()s.

Comment: i think $RMM makes no diff in the code from my own understanding

Comment: Since the companies are mapped to a user change to `$user =User::find($RMM->user_id);` that's the only way `$user` will have a value

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, when you `dd()` something it die at first iteration in `foreach`, error may occurs in another iterates, maybe id 1 is exists in user but 3 or 4 is not.

Comment: I want to find post from company id. Company check for user registered under it, than check for post created by user. The result are posts related to the user from the company. Thank you for the advice. Will change it.

Comment: Yes sir. I do aware of it. I'm using it just to make sure the output is what i want.

Comment: it seems from the company record, the user id could not be found that's why. You would have to check if the id exists before proceeding with your query.

Comment: @JuliusFasema, if you look at `dd()` result, I properly got the result for each query, the weird thing is, when I remove `dd()` the error will appear even though the result already there. I used `dd()` after `$user = User::find($RMM->user_id)` for `dd($user)` and smilar to `dd($post).

Comment: in your company record, are you getting the user id? dd($RMM) lets see what you are having

Comment: If what you mean is getting user info/id from company id, it is `$user = User::find($RMM->id);` and the result is [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKOqP.png)

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
$RMM_details = Company::where('branch', 'RMM')->get();
            $RMM_details->transform(function($RMM)use($user){
            $user = User::find($RMM->id);
            $post = post::find($user->id);
                return [
                    'title' => $post->article_title,
                    'name' => $post->author,
                    'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post->date)),
                ];
            });
```

Comment: [ERROR] Undefined variable: user. 
How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because
$post = post::find($user->id);
is returning null value at some stances.

Check if it is empty or not by using the function empty and try again.

```
 $RMM = DB::table('companies')->where('branch', 'RMM')->get();
    foreach ($RMM as $RMM) {
        $user = User::find($RMM->id);
if(!empty($user->id){
        $post = post::find($user->id);
}
        $post_data = array('title' => $post->article_title,
            'name' => $post->author,
            'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post->date)),
        );
```